# Expand the table fit to the page

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Summary Statistics} 
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l c c c c  }
\hline\hline
Variable & Mean & Median & Pct 25 & Pct 75 \\ 
\hline
Log Price & -1.023& -1.021&-1.206 & -.844 \\ 
Log Quantity &1.23 &1.23 &1.13 &1.33 \\ 
\hline\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:summary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I try to my table fit to the page using above coding. But, it only extends size of table, not contents.(It means that there are extra spaces following fifth columns) Is there anyone who knows what I have done wrong?
Thank you for help!!

Comment: `tabularx` requires an `X` column to be able to adjust the width, but _please_ don't do this! separating the columns of data tables just makes the table harder to read and has no benefits. Better to leave teh table its natural width but use `dcolumn` or `siunitx` columns to align the numeric columns on the decimal point

Answer (score 2):

I would not stretch the table to the full line width. It makes reading the table harder. Instead I would use rules from package `booktabs`, which has thicker rules for the top and bottom and adds the necessary vertical spaces.
The numbers can be aligned with package `booktab`'s column type `S`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Summary Statistics}
  \label{table:summary}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
  }
    \toprule
    Variable & {Mean} & {Median} & {Pct 25} & {Pct 75} \\
    \midrule
    Log Price & -1.023& -1.021&-1.206 & -0.844 \\
    Log Quantity &1.23 &1.23 &1.13 &1.33 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For comparison, the following version adds space between the columns to fill the line width:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Summary Statistics}
  \label{table:summary}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
    !{\extracolsep\fill}
    l
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
  }
    \toprule
    Variable & {Mean} & {Median} & {Pct 25} & {Pct 75} \\
    \midrule
    Log Price & -1.023& -1.021&-1.206 & -0.844 \\
    Log Quantity &1.23 &1.23 &1.13 &1.33 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result wide version]

Comment: You quickly noticed that I am a baby in latex world. Thank you for kind answer, Heiko. Now, my table looks great!!!

Comment: Thanks Heiko! Surprised to see just a couple of up votes. This is indeed better answer than dumb `\resizebox` or `\adjustbox`.